# Perl from command line: When replace a string in a file it removes also the new lines

Tags: perl, file, command-line, replace

I'm using perl from command line to to replace duplicate spaces from a text file.

The command I use is:

```
perl -pi -e 's/\s+/ /g' file.csv
```

The problem: This procedure removes also the new lines in the resulting file....

Any idea why this occur?

Thanks!

Comment: Which Perl version is this on which operating system?

Comment: $ perl -v = This is perl 5, version 12, subversion 4 (v5.12.4) built for x86_64-linux-gnu-thread-multi

Comment: This is because `\s` also matches a new line. It matches any whitespace character

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`\s` means the five characters: `[ \f\n\r\t]`. So, you're replacing newlines by single spaces.
In your case, the simplest way is to enable automatic line-ending processing with `-l` flag:

```
perl -pi -le 's/\s+/ /g' file.csv
```

This way, newlines will be chomped before `-e` statement and appended after.

Answer (score 0):

Will add my two cents to the previous answer.
If you use this regexp in perl script itself, then you can just change it to:

```
s/[ ]+/ /gis;
```

That will change every line and won't delete line-endings.

Comment: The flags `is` are completely redundant here. Space does not have a case to ignore, and `s` just makes the wildcard `.` match newline.